# Autosave on 'belongs_to` Association Fails To Save Associated Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations, belongs-to

I have a `Parent` model that maintains a set of `Tags` based on an aggregation of all the tags of its children:

```
model Parent
   before_save :agregate_tags

   has_many :children
   has_many :tags

   def agregate_tags
     self.tags = self.children.flat_map(&:tags).uniq
   end

end
```

The Child model:

```
class Child
   belongs_to :parent, autosave: true
   has_many :tags
end
```

**When I save the `Child` the parent is not saved. Why might this be?**

When I save `child` here are no errors and there is no database activity related to `Parent`. It seems that no attempt is made to save it.

If I create a `before_save` callback on Child and save `parent` there, it saves successfully without error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you saving `child`?  If you're not creating or modifying an association with parent, rails doesn't modify the parent record.  Would you really want rails updating `parent` needlessly every time you modify a child?

You'll need to use `before_save` to do what you wish (as you've mentioned).

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. So in this case I would want to check if the  Child model's `tags` association has changed in a before_save callback and only save its `parent` if it has?

Comment: That's what _I_ would do. ;)